# How can I insert a line break at the end of divs that have not wrapped?

Tags: html, css

I'm slurping in xml that has text marked up into words, lines and paragraphs, and spitting out html/css. I would like to respect the existing line breaks if the screen is wide enough, but if not I just want to let the browser do the line-wrapping.

Here's what I get if I just insert a `<br/>` at the end of every existing line:

Desktop (looks good!):
This is a fairly long line, and it wraps here
and we move on to the next line, which also ends
moving on to the third line, line number three.

Mobile (what I get):
This is a fairly long line, and
it wraps here
and we move on to the next line,
which also ends
moving on to the third line,
line number three.

Mobile (what I want):
This is a fairly long line, and
it wraps here and we move on to
the next line, which also ends
moving on to the third line, line
number three.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the `br` tag, could you hide it on mobile using CSS? I'm thinking something like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   br {
       display: none;
   }
 }
```

This will let the browser take control of the text resizing as it gets to the mobile size, rather than manually breaking the lines.